# Error Installing Pytorch+cuda121 in Poetry Virtual Environment: Source (pytorch): Authorization error accessing https://download.pytorch.org/

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, yolo, python-poetry

I am looking to use the yolov5 model and opencv in my project. I am currently using Poetry as the virtual environment for my project.

In order to operate yolov5 with gpu rather than cpu, I am looking to install cuda. I am trying to download the Cuda 12.1 version from https://pytorch.org/. For this, I have configured my pyproject.toml as follows:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "yolo-test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = [""]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "yolo_test"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.11,<3.13"
opencv-python = "^4.8.0.74"
pyinstaller = "^6.1.0"
pillow = "^10.1.0"
pandas = "^2.1.1"
requests = "^2.31.0"
ultralytics = "^8.0.201"
logging = "^0.4.9.6"

# Cuda installation test
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Afterwards, I tried to install it in the poetry virtual environment using the following command:

```bash
poetry add torch torchvision torchaudio --source pytorch
```

However, during the installation, I observed the following error logs:

```
Source (pytorch): Authorization error accessing https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/pefile/
Source (pytorch): Authorization error accessing https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/macholib/
Source (pytorch): Authorization error accessing https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/logging/
Source (pytorch): Authorization error accessing https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/ultralytics/
...
```

Additionally, I used `print(torch.__version__)` for verification, and as an output, I observed `2.1.0+cpu`.
Could anyone assist me on how to install the Pytorch Cuda version in Poetry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your PyTorch source is used for all the dependencies listed in your TOML file.

The correct way to is to only use the PyTorch source for the PyTorch and TorchVision dependencies. You can achieve this by using the `explicit` source priority:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "yolo-test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = [""]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "yolo_test"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.11,<3.13"
torch = { version = "^2.1.0", source = "pytorch" }
opencv-python = "^4.8.0.74"
pyinstaller = "^6.1.0"
pillow = "^10.1.0"
pandas = "^2.1.1"
requests = "^2.31.0"
ultralytics = "^8.0.201"
logging = "^0.4.9.6"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121"
priority = "explicit"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

With this settings, only the `torch` dependency will use the `pytorch` source.